# Can you also use 'sorry' when you're regretting something?

Tags: german-to-english

A few days ago, I was wandering around and I wanted to go to a shop. When I looked on the door, it said: 'Sorry, wir sind geschlossen'. Does this mean that you can use 'sorry' when you regret something instead of 'entschuldigung' or 'es tut mir leid'?

Also, when I was watching 'Sturm der Liebe' I noticed that it has been said multiple times. I don't know if you know these series, but here in Belgium, it's very popular with older people like me :) .

Comment: Are you sure, that it was »*Sorry, wir **sind** geschlossen*«? This would be correct: »*Sorry, wir **haben** geschlossen*«.

Comment: That's also possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since world war II English has a very big influence on German language. Everybody living in Germany and Austria (and I guess also in Switzerland) who is now younger than about 60 years did learn English as a student in School. Many younger people even started learning English in preschool. Also many people are using English every day in their jobs, and we have some radio stations broadcasting only or mainly in English.

So in German spoken countries the knowledge of English is very high, and so a big amount of English words have been included into German language in the last decades. (These words are called *anglicisms*, there are thousands of them in the German language.)

Some German words are long and bulky, and if there is an English word with the same meaning, that is slim and slips out of the mouth easily, then the chances are high, that it will be used instead the original German word:

> **Entschuldigung** - 4 syllables, 1 clumsy consonant-cluster (»ntsch«)
>   **sorry** - 2 syllables, 0 consonant-clusters

So, »sorry« has establish itself as an adequate alternative to »Entschuldigung«.

btw:
»Entschuldigung« is just an ellipsis. The full expression would be:

> **Ich bitte um Entschuldigung** - 4 words, 8 syllables, 1 consonant-cluster
>   **Wir bitten um Entschuldigung** - 4 words, 8 syllables, 1 consonant-cluster
>
> **sorry** - 1 word, 2 syllables, 0 consonant-clusters

Another German alternative is:

> **Es tut mir/uns leid** - 4 words, 4 syllables

Comment: *Verzeihung* oder gar *Pardon* erlauben ein weiteres Drücken der Silbenzahl; ich habe allerdings meine Zweifel, ob das für die Wortwahl ausschlaggebend ist.

Comment: @guidot: Weder das deutsche *Verzeihung* noch das französische *pardon* sind meiner Wahrnehmung nach üblich, wenn man sich mit einem Schild, das man an die Türe eines Geschäftes hängt, im Voraus für etwas entschuldigen möchte.

Comment: "Sorry" is *trendiger hipper Jugendslang.* Zumindest sehen das die verschrobenen altgewordenen Macher solcher Seifenopern so. Früher hätte man "Schullijun" genuschelt.

Comment: @Janka: Ich sage auch häufig »sorry« und bin 51. Jugendslang ist das keineswegs. Dass die Macher von Seifenopern in ihren eigenen Welten leben, glaube ich gerne, aber dass sie ihren Figuren das Wort »sorry« in dem Mund legen, betrachte ich nicht als Beleg dafür. Die Menschen sagen das wirklich.

Comment: Ich sehe das eher als Beweis an, dass zuviel Seifenopern geguckt werden. Du bist aufgrund von Englischkenntnissen entschuldigt.